# How do i pass my class as parameter (Entity Framework 6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am having quite some trouble passing the Class type as paramater, since they represent tables and i only want to retrieve the result as a list

My function that takes the list is `setDados(ds)`

```
public void setDados(List<RP_EntityFrameWork_Tentativa.marcas> data)
{
        gridControl1.DataSource = data;
        gridView1.PopulateColumns();
        Debug.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Which i have to before hand specify what class the list type is.

is there a way to be able to declare something along the lines of `List<Class>` or just pass a class as a parameter ?

all the classes i need to pass follow this same "Template"/Writing Style

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RP_EntityFrameWork_Tentativa
{
    public class marcas
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Marca { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Descmarca { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nat { get; set; }

        //ligação carros
        public virtual ICollection<carros> carros{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

i am currently using the following method

```
 
private void abreListaGeral(DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit txt, List<marcas> ds, bool multiselect, int mode, int indexProcura)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            String str = "";

            frmQueryList lista = new frmQueryList();

            lista.multiselect = multiselect;
            lista.mode = mode;
            lista.indexProcura = indexProcura;
            lista.btnNovo.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemVisibility.Never;
            lista.btnNovo.Enabled = false;
            lista.setDados(ds);
            lista.ShowDialog();
            str = lista.resultado2;
            txt.Text = lista.resultado;

            lista.frmIniciado = false;
            lista.Close();
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
```

Which works but i have to create a new method for every Class i need to use this way create a bunch of overrites and useless code that could surely be optimized

What i am looking for is to have `abreListaGeral()` take as arguments such as `List<marcas>` `List<carros>` `List<etc>` without having to previously specify it

Comment: `private void abreListaGeral<T>(DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit txt, List<T> ds, bool multiselect, int mode, int indexProcura)` - make it a generic one?

Comment: BTW in `setDados` you are not actually _using_ `db`. So why create it?

Comment: Ur right i dont use it it was a previous attempt, Thank you soo much for you help, it worked as intended